# Update Version of Visual Studio C++ project EXE post build in TeamCity

Tags: visual-studio-2015, teamcity

I have an old Visual Studio (2015) C++ project that I am working on. There was no way to automatically update the product version. The current version was fixed at `4.6.0`. The project is also hosted on `TeamCity` server for build releases.
The `resource file(.rc file)` of the project is `Service.rc` as below:

```
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated resource script.
//
#include "resource.h"

#define APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 2 resource.
//
#include "afxres.h"

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#undef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// English (U.S.) resources

#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_ENU)
#ifdef _WIN32
LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US
#pragma code_page(1252)
#endif //_WIN32

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Icon
//

// Icon with lowest ID value placed first to ensure application icon
// remains consistent on all systems.
IDI_MSPSERVER           ICON                    "service.ico"

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// TEXTINCLUDE
//

1 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "resource.h\0"
END

2 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "#include ""afxres.h""\r\n"
    "\0"
END

3 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "\r\n"
    "\0"
END

#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Version
//

VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
 FILEVERSION 4,6,0,0
 PRODUCTVERSION 4,6,0,0
 FILEFLAGSMASK 0x3fL
#ifdef _DEBUG
 FILEFLAGS 0x1L
#else
 FILEFLAGS 0x0L
#endif
 FILEOS 0x40004L
 FILETYPE 0x1L
 FILESUBTYPE 0x0L
BEGIN
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "040904b0"
        BEGIN
            VALUE "CompanyName", "Home"
            VALUE "FileDescription", "Service App"
            VALUE "FileVersion", "4.6.0"
            VALUE "InternalName", "Service"
            VALUE "LegalCopyright", "Copyright © 2018"
            VALUE "OriginalFilename", "MyService.exe"
            VALUE "ProductName", "Home Service"
            VALUE "ProductVersion", "4.6.0"
        END
    END
    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        VALUE "Translation", 0x409, 1200
    END
END

#endif    // English (U.S.) resources
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



#ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 3 resource.
//


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#endif    // not APSTUDIO_INVOKED
```

Is there a way that I can setup `TeamCity` builds so that the version is updated post builds every time ? Like if my build is `4.6.0.200` the version info about this executable is also updated from `4.6.0.0` to `4.6.0.200` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Prior to compilation resource files (.rc) are being processed by a C-style preprocessor. So the idea is to generate a version info header file and to include it into code instead of hardcoding version numbers everywhere:

```
#ifndef VERSION_INFO_H_
#define VERSION_INFO_H_

#define APP_VERSION_MAJOR 4
#define APP_VERSION_MAJOR_SZ "4"
#define APP_VERSION_MINOR 6
#define APP_VERSION_MINOR_SZ "6"
…

#endif // ifndef VERSION_INFO_H_
```

In resource file:

```
#include "Version Info.h"

FILEVERSION APP_VERSION_MAJOR,APP_VERSION_MINOR,0,0
…
VALUE "ProductVersion", APP_VERSION_MAJOR_SZ "." APP_VERSION_MINOR_SZ ".0"
```